# Plot a narrow map region using Python Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I would like to plot a map using Basemap (I am not aware of other Python libraries). I am interested in the region centred at latitude 42.9509 and longitude 12.7015, with a radius of 100 km.

I use the following code but the resolution of the image is very low.

```
lat_0 = 42.9509
lon_0 = 12.7015

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
m = Basemap(projection='lcc', resolution='f',
            width=0.3E6, height=0.3E6,
            lat_0=lat_0, lon_0=lon_0)

m.etopo(scale=1, alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I would like an image where I could see more details to plot points scattered on top of that.

Comment: Instead of using `m.etopo()` I'd use `m.arcgimage()`. When you zoom in that close using `m.etopo()`, `m.bluemarble()`, or `m.shadedrelief()`, it becomes blurry even if you were to save it as a high resolution image. Link to the [documentation](http://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backgrounds.html) explaining this.

Comment: @BrandonMolyneaux Thanks!